# Could not cast value of type 'TableViewController' to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsstring, segue

I'm getting following error in the fourth line of below code...

> *Thread 1: signal SIGABRT*, and the output says *Could not cast value of type 'JobTableViewController' (0x10a20cb80) to 'NSString' (0x10cc5a2a8).*

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails" {
        let detailController = segue.destination as! JobDetailViewController
        detailController.valueToPass = sender as! String
    }
}
```

Job.swift:

```
class Job {
var text: String = ""
let ref: DatabaseReference!

init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
{
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        text = value["text"] as! String
    }
}

func save() {
    ref.setValue(toDictionary())
}

func toDictionary() -> [String : Any]
{
    return [
        "text" : text,
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: What is the class of the view controller performing this segue? And what is the value you want to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in `performSegue` you send `self` ( which is of type `JobTableViewController`) as `sender` parameter like this

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: self)
```

and here cast it to

```
sender as! String
```

so convert it to

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender:"sendedStr")
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't know if I understand you right... what do I need to change now?

Comment: You mean "sentStr" or "senderStr", typo?

Comment: He means the String you send, so in my case "valueToPass", and oh, it's working, thank you :)

Comment: @Carpsen90 as joe said =D

Comment: One more question: When my sender is just ValueToPass, without "", I get the same error, just for the file Job.swift, instead of the JobTableViewController... what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: then ValueToPass should be of String type